# The definition of a rational function and $f(x) = {1}/{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, rational-functions

I have a small question:

> Can one state that $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$ is a rational function because it is the quotient between a polynomial with degree 0 and a polynomial with degree 1?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this is the case.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thank you my friend, I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is true.

The rational functions is the field of fractions of the ring of polynomials. $x$ is a polynomial, so $x^{-1}$ is in the field of fractions.